# Pasar entre actividades, Fragmentos

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Eh estado trabajando con `Activity` y `Fragments`, de los cuales sé como pasar de una actividad a otra y de un fragmento a otro,.....Pero como hago para pasar de un Fragmento a una actividad? acá les dejo el código :)

1.- Pasar de una actividad a otra:

```
cambio.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent miintento= new Intent ( getApplicationContext (),PopUpTabla.class );
                startActivity ( miintento );
            }
        } );
```

2.- Pasar de un Fragmento a otro:

```
BCliente.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tabla_cliente= new Tbl_Cliente ();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, tbl_cliente);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        } );
```

3.- Pasar de un Fragmento a una actividad:

??? -- ayuda :(

---

4.-Y tengo otra duda, como hago para pasar de un `activity` hacia un fragmento? (mi `activity` es un pop up, no hay ningún problema?)....

- Hice asi (un poquito de código no se si estará bien o no), quiero que al darle click en un `TextView` me mande de "regreso" al fragmento anterior:

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext (), Frg_And_Inventario.class);

startActivity(intent);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- y en el manifest lo tengo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Pero ni aún así me genera el mismo error:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android/sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.Herramt_Almacen.Frg_And_Inventario}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

- Ayuda por favor! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para abrir desde un `Fragment` a un Actividad la única forma es abrirla mediante un [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)**, debes usar `getActivity()` para obtener el contexto de `la Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtraActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
BCliente.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PopUpTabla.class);
             startActivity(intent);

            }
        } );
```

Comment: Graciasss :) :)

Comment: Hola, un favor utilicé el código que me diste y todo me quedó okey pero ahora tengo problemas, al querer abrir un fragmento desde un actovity (todo lo contrario) y en el error me dice que deberia de declararlo en el manifets. ayuda por favor no se que hacer.

Comment: Si!, de hecho agrega la Activity en tu AndroidManifest.xml. Por ejemplo    <activity android:name=".OtraActivity"/> @Bloom Si tienes problemas puedes agregar otra pregunta y te ayudo.

Comment: si lo puse en el manifest pero aún así me pase ese error. Es que yo estoy utilizando una tabla pop up y cuando le doy click a un texto quiero que regrese a un fragmento anterior. pero no me esta saliendo :(

Comment: @Bloom mmm que raro, la clase activity que agregas debe extender de Activity o AppCompatActivity, etc, te sugiero agrear una pregunta con toda la información y te ayudamos sin problema.

Comment: mira, acomode mi pregunta, ahí especifíco y pongo imágenes. por favor ayuda

Comment: Lo que defines en el intent como Frg_And_Inventario.class es la activity que deseas abrir 1) esta debe extender de Activity y 2) esta debe ser registrada en el AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Pero el Frg_And_Inventario no es un activity es un fragmento solo And_Buscar_Datos (tabla pop up) es el activity. por eso pregunto como paso de un activity a un fragmento :( :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88149/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-bloom).